# How to have multiple sections in the same theme options page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

For my theme, I have created a Settings Page which is shown in the Appearance menu of Wordpress admin.

Now, I have been following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-5-tabbed-navigation-for-your-settings-page--wp-24971).

Exactly like the tutorial, I have created multiple sections and I face the issue where only the fields of the last section are saved in the DB while the fields of other sections are not saved.

I do not want to go for the Tabbed Navigation option - I have too many sections.

How do I solve the problem of not being able to save fields of other sections due to the nonce issue?

EDIT: I am using Wordpress 3.3.1

Comment: You may be interested in having a look on my admin panel: https://github.com/maximski/Inferno it provides an easy syntax to create full featured and accessible admin options :) (and is pretty beautiful by the way)

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate section forms...

Just like this:--

```
<?php if( $active_tab == 'display_options' ) { ?>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php
    settings_fields( 'sandbox_theme_display_options' );
    do_settings_sections( 'sandbox_theme_display_options' );
    submit_button();
    ?>
</form>
<?php } else { ?>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php
    settings_fields( 'sandbox_theme_social_options' );
    do_settings_sections( 'sandbox_theme_social_options' );
    submit_button();
    ?>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

May be this will help you...

---

In tutorial document, Form is like following...

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php

        if( $active_tab == 'display_options' ) {
            settings_fields( 'sandbox_theme_display_options' );
            do_settings_sections( 'sandbox_theme_display_options' );
        } else {
            settings_fields( 'sandbox_theme_social_options' );
            do_settings_sections( 'sandbox_theme_social_options' );
        } // end if/else

        submit_button();

    ?>
</form>
```

This is also separate form content.

Comment: This will show multiple submit buttons for each form. I want just one submit form (like in the tutorial) but it should be able to submit each section.

Comment: Erm... It uses tabs - I had mentioned I don't want tabs. I want multiple sections, one submit button and it should save data of all the sections. I have a feeling that if I adjust the settings group, this should work.. though, using the tutorial  example, I am not able to figure out which one...